# What is the difference between storing data in plist vs setting up data in scene editor in Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

It may not appear to be a wise question to ask but I have confusion in mind which I want to clear. In Apple's 2d game framework Sprite kit, normally it is suggested to store data related to nodes in Plist and then retrieve when required in code. What i don't get is while using .sks scene editor you have opportunity to set and store data related to nodes in attributes inspector.Or I am misunderstanding it? What is the difference in both approaches or setting data related to nodes by using .sks scene editor through attribute inspector does not get stored anywhere and only accessible dynamically. I would appreciate if someone can state the clear difference between these two approaches. I have tried to look for it but could not get any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go simple on that matter.  PLists are perfect to store data that is more general.  Like game settings, etc.  If you need to store data related directly to a node, then use the node's User Data.

It is important to understand that in a game where you have, let's say, spawning ennemies, you could/should store the information about the different *ennemy types* in a plist.
When the ennemies are spawned, they will have different attributes that will make them unique even though a bunch of them are of the same type.  It could be color, health points, level, etc.  If you need that data serialized and saved for later use, it should go in the user data.

Based on what I just said, I don't know, performance wise, if user data is very efficient when it comes to data that changes a lot (like health points, for instance). I feel like in that situation, using a custom class and adding properties to store that data might make things go faster, but in that case, if you need the data serialized, you will have to implement the NSCoding protocol.

---

**Edit**

Based on your comments here is some clarification:

If you are only working on your scene in xCode's scene editor, then you might not see the real difference between User Data and using a plist.  If you never create sprites by code then it's not obvious.

*Why plists?*

If you create your characters by code, then it might be interesting to use plists to store the "model information".  As you mentionned, the video presentation made by Apple about SpriteKit best practices is talking about storing information such as the anchor, the position, scale and the like in a plist.  For example, if you are making a space ship game, you might want to have different spaceship models.  They might have very different shapes and because of that you might not want them to rotate around the same point for it to look good.  They will also have different textures and different stats (max health points, max shield, etc).  In the plist you can then store things like that:

- ship model 1

  - texture: ship1.png
  - anchor: (0.5, 0.5)
  - maxhealth: 100
  - maxshield: 100
  - ...
- ship model 2

  - texture: ship2.png
  - anchor: (0.2, 0.5)
  - maxhealth: 150
  - maxshield: 200
  - ...
- ...

If you are working with a graphist, it's easy for him to edit a plist without getting involved with xCode.  So when his graphics are ready, he can fill in the informations about the texture and the anchor (for example) by himself and let the game designer add the other stats, etc.

Then, if you create a ship in the code, simply retrieve the informations from the plist to create the new ship with all the correct settings.

Over time, the graphist can update the graphics and related info in the plist and you won't even need to recompile to test the new content.  You can even use generic pictures (or a solid color when no picture is provided) to develop features before you even get the graphics material.

*Why use UserData?*

Your spaceships are created and you are fighting for your life.  At some point, someome will get hurt and you will need to keep track of it.  You could do it easily with variables, but then, it you want to use NSCoder to save your game state, you will have to do it by hand.
If you store specific information about a sprite, then UserData is the key.  It's something that is specific to THAT node only.  It will also get saved with all the rest when you use NSCoder to save your game state.
This is ponctual data.  Health will greatly vary during the course of the game, but when you load your last save, you want the boss you were fighting to be hurt just like it was when you saved.  So it's ponctual, but persistent.  And it's related only to that node.  So it makes sense to store it in the node itself.

*Performances*

As with anything you might worry about performance.  If you have hundreds of sprites all getting hurt and healed non-stop, it might bottleneck if you update the userData all the time.  If you ever get to that point, you might consider subclassing from the SKSpriteNode , adding a variable to keep track of the health and such and instead of dealing with the NSCoder stuff directly, simply commit the content of your variables to the userData when you need to save it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your perspective on it. As I am just a casual programmer and quite new to game programming and Apple framework I would like to be as simple as possible to go about it. You have given a sound explanation of which data can be stored in plist and what should go to user data but yet as I described above the speaker in WWDC 2013 I suppose discussed best practices and he was talking to separate data like position, anchor point, rotation from logic. He suggested to using plists for this purpose to store this data as well I am not sure why he would. Still confused between two

Comment: I think I know what video you are talking about.  It's dating a little bit IIRC.  The upside I can see with using a plist for sprite related data is that since it's only a text file, it can be edited outside xCode.  This would give the graphic designers the opportunity to work on the details.  If you are working with IK, for example, you will need to divide your characters into body parts to animate them.  With a plist, the designers can edit it themselves and give you all the infos such as the anchors, positions, etc.  It really depends on your workflow I guess.

Comment: I kept thinking about it and I will edit my answer to give more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for breaking this into simple to understand pieces of info. I am working on first Sprite Kit game, was confused a lot between these two ways of storing data. It was a huge help from you and RonMyschuk.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently started using the Scene editor for all aspects of my game. Not just the scenes but to create complex SKSPriteNode objects, modular popups, etc. It has mostly been great, and a lot quicker than trying to layout the objects in code.

So if I could keep all of the data in the sks file even better.

Yes, you are correct you can set and store data relevant to the node in the scene editor. It's in the Attributes Inspector under User Data.

You can also store that info in a Plist file. However a big difference between the two methods is that if you store the data in the Plist file you have to then sort through the data and find the relevant data and bind it to the node. When using User Data the data is already bound to the node and goes with it, so you don't have to find it associate it later.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata).

> You use this property to store your own data in a node. For example,
>   you might store game-specific data about each node to use inside your
>   game logic. This can be a useful alternative to creating your own node
>   subclasses to hold game data. SpriteKit does not do anything with the
>   data stored in the node. However, the data is archived when the node
>   is archived.

Here is an example of how easy it is to access User Data stored from an sks file

```
if let userData = redVillian.userData {
    if let hitPoints = userData.object(forKey: "hitPoints") as? Int {
        redVillain.hitPoints = hitPoints
    }
    if let name = userData.object(forKey: "name") as? String {
        redVillian.name = name
    }
}
```

You can also set the User Data in code

```
redVillian.userData = ["hitPoints": 5, "name" : "Herbert"]
```

or modify it in code

```
redVillian.userData?.setValue("Eleanor", forKey: "name")
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a detailed answer to differ between two approaches but something is still not very clear to me. I had watched WWDC where they were discussing best practices in spritekit and I remember when explained separating game data from logic by moving to plists and he was referring to data like position, rotation, scale etc related to nodes. If I am not mistaken they talked about scene editor later but the speaker did not mention explicitly to store data inside scene editor. That makes things unclear to me.

Comment: One more thing if you can elaborate, what data must be stored as user data? In your example code you saved and retrieved data like name in and from user data as well but there is already field in scene editor by default where you can save name and properties like position, anchor point or rotation. So what kind of data relate to nodes can be saved under user data. I appreciate your help and sorry if I am talking like a naive but I am absolute beginner to this language let alone to the sprite kit.

Comment: yeah I guess "name" was a poor example. In one of my games (a post apocalyptic driving game) I have over 2 dozen different enemy vehicle types. For each vehicle I setup a master in the scene editor and apply variables for their type to the userData. specifically I set mass, speed, damage, armor & collision dimensions. Then when I need an instance of the vehicle I make a copy() and voila it instantly has all of the info it needs for the vehicle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the type of data that you can store is bound to the same limitations as plist and userDefaults. Array, Data, Dictionary, Number & String

Comment: Thank you for your help Ron. I have a better idea now what to use and when.